# PHP connectivity to Oracle DB

Tags: php, database, oracle, crm

I am currently trying to write a PHP script to connect to an Oracle database. The reason I am using PHP is because I need to connect the Oracle database with my current CRM system, written in PHP/MySQL.

The PHP is hosted on 1&1 hosting, which is an external server. I read that I need to enable the extension php_oci8.dll to connect using oci_connect(), but I cannot do so since I do not have root privileges. Did a search, and couldn't find the DLL either.

Is there any other way around this? Any help greatly appreciated, please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) 1&1 will have Linux, so you will have to use linux names for extensions. In this case name of extension will be `php_oci8.so`

2) create the `php.ini` in root directory and put the following line
`extension=php_oci8.so`

3) create a simple php script with one line to test if it works:
`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Please note -- 1&1 may physically not have that file available on their server (or some additional libraries that may be required by that extension). If the problem just with absence of .so file, then you can provide your own version of it (upload it and put the correct full path to the extension in php.ini)

Useful links: 1) http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/php/6.html 2) http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/php/8.html

Comment: It seems that there is no php_oci8.so extension available in 1&1. I added the line: `extension=php_oci8.so` to the php.ini, and ran phpinfo() but it did not show up there. To be sure, I also ran extension_loaded() and it failed too. Where can I find this php_oci8.so file? I've tried google, but couldn't find it. Do I need root privileges to install the file as a package? Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Well, you may compile it yourself or grab it from already compiled PHP installation package (sorry, I'm not linux user). But I would suggest to contact 1&1 first -- usually they are very good at answering questions -- at least they can tell you if they can help here (provide the file compiled specifically for their machines) or if this will not be possible at all. My answer above is just general approach, which will work for sure if you have all files necessary.

Comment: Made a phone call to 1&1, it seems that I need to get a Dedicated server with Root access and configure the php_oci8 myself.. I hope this is not the only option though. Do you happen to know if the Oci8 is the only way to interface between PHP and Oracle? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you look into standard PHP config file (php.ini) it has 3 native options: 1) php_oci8 (Use with Oracle 10gR2 Instant Client); 2) php_oci8_11g (Use with Oracle 11g Instant Client); 3) php_pdo_oci (to be used with PDO). But because Oracle is such specific database to be used on shared hosting, I doubt that you will easily find any hoster that offers them by default. If going with Dedicated server is too expensive, have a look at virtual servers -- it still be only-your server but generally cheaper (not hugely like shared hosting is, but maybe half of dedicated -- depends).

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem. first thing is that linux doesn't support .dll file.
You have to install OCI8 extension module in your Apache server.
Follow this link to get easy solution.

http://coffeewithcode.com/2012/09/how-to-install-oracle-libraries-for-php5-on-ubuntu-server/

Answer (score 0):

Please check that there are no blank spaces. 
1. put the php.ini and the php_oci8.so in the same folder as where you are going to run the php program that is going to access the database.
2. php.ini contents should look like:

```
extesion=./php_oci8.so
```